# why is my original list array is getting modified

Tags: java, list, reference

why when I call

```
ArrayList<String> reversedList = ListUtils.reverse(list);
```

is modifying the original list, even though I'm making a copy of it inside the method

```
package com.javablackbelt.utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class ListUtils {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        String[] arr = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
        ArrayUtils.print(arr);

        System.out.println();

        String [] reversedArr = ArrayUtils.reverse(arr);
        ArrayUtils.print(reversedArr);

        System.out.println();

        ArrayList<String> list = ArrayUtils.toArrayList(arr);
        ListUtils.print(list);  

        ArrayList<String> reversedList = ListUtils.reverse(list);
        ListUtils.print(reversedList);

        String[] arrFromList = ListUtils.toArray(list);
        ArrayUtils.print(arrFromList);

    }

    public static void print(ArrayList<String> aStr) {
        System.out.print("list: [ ");
        for(String l: aStr)
            System.out.print(l+" ");
        System.out.println(" ] size: "+aStr.size());
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> reverse(ArrayList<String> aList) {
        ArrayList<String> newList = aList;

        Collections.reverse(newList);
        return newList;
    }

    public static String[] toArray(ArrayList<String> list) {
        ArrayList<String> newList = list;
        String[] newStr = newList.toArray(new String[list.size()]);

        return newStr;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's very unclear where you think you're making a copy. Can you narrow it down for us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ArrayList<String> newList = aList;` is not creating a new list. It creates a new reference to the same list.

Creating a new list could be done this way:

```
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(aList.size());
for (String str : aList)
    newList.add(str);
```

Thx @JB Nizet
This is much simpler:

```
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(aList);
```

Comment: Or, much simpler: `List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(aList);`

Comment: @JBNizet Ohh man that way does the work of creating a new list and copying it in one line... great job

Comment: Yes. All the collections have one such copy constructor, as you can discover by reading the javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `ArrayList<String> newList = aList;` you are not creating a new list but pointing newList to `aList`. create a new ArrayList and add the `aList` into that `newList` if you dont wanna modify the existing list.

```
public static ArrayList<String> reverse(ArrayList<String> aList) {
            ArrayList<String> newList= new ArrayList<>();
                     newList.addAll( aList);

            Collections.reverse(newList);
            return newList;
        }
```

**EDIT:**

```
use Collections.copy(List dest, List src) to copy.
```

[check here for Collections API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#copy%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29)

Comment: is it possible to use System.arraycopy() with lists? like in arrays?... I tried creating a new one and then copying it using arraycopy, but I'm getting runtime errors

Comment: You're getting compile errors. arrays and lists are different kinds of objects. You can't pass a List to a method extecting an array. Just kike you can't pass an Apple to a method expecting an Orange. There's this little helpful thing called the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/), which is freely available, and which exposes all the methods of every class in the JDK, along with their documentation. Read it.